# Remove leading zeros at the time of comparison from both side of model-attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models `Product` and `RetailerProduct`. I want to establish a `one-to-one` relationship between this models. The relationship logic is complex and it will eat all performance. So, we decided to populate `retailer_product_id` in `products` table with batch-job.

The problem is that we have one condition where we have to match `products.matching_data` with `retailer_products.matching_code`. Both of this tables contains leading zeros in somecase and we want to ignore that leading zeros. For some reason,i can't change the data-type of columns.

The problem is the below query only removes the zeros from one side. I want to be removed in both side.

```
retailer_products = RetailerProduct.find(11223) // just initialising retailer_product variable  
Product.where matching_data: retailer_products.matching_code.sub(/^[0:]*/,"")
```

example, the above query will fail with below data.It will just match one row but logically both of this rows matches.

Retailer_product table

```
retailer_products | matching_code
1                 | "0123a"
2                 | "139"
```

Product table

```
products           | matching_data
1                  | "123a"
2                  | "0139"
```

Comment: Why not trim the leading zeros from the data itself, and ensure things stay that way in the future?

Comment: because leading zeros hold importance in other condition and other models, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the SQL level:

```
trim(leading '0' FROM '01390');
```

`trim` is an SQL-standard function so Ruby/Rails probably offers a way to invoke it during query construction.

That way you can write sensible join conditions. I can't Rails-ify it (don't speak Rails) but in SQL, things like:

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
INNER JOIN retailer_product rp ON (trim(leading '0' from rp.matching_data) = trim(leading '0' from p.matching_data));
```

Comment: this works. Thanks. Only, you have remove extra parentheses, pluralise  table names and use `leading` instead of `both`.

Comment: I misread your statement "The problem is the below query only removes the zeros from one side. I want to be removed in both side.". Yeah. Obviously you don't want to remove zeroes from both sides of the number. Fixing. As for pluralise table names: If you want exact runnable SQL, **post your table definitions** (SQLFiddle.com is good for this). Otherwise we get to guess the details.